# How do I simplify and calculate this inequality?

Tags: inequality, logarithms

$\log(x^3) > |x-1|$

I can't figure out how to go about solving this inequality, besides this one step:

$3\log(x) > |x-1|$

Comment: Try two different cases: $x \geq 1$ and $x < 1$. You'll have two different inequalities, and unless the original inequality is false, they will give you the same thing.

Comment: The case for $ \ 0 \ < \ x \ <  \ 1 \ $ is the easy one.  You can probably spot where equality holds.  For the $ \ x \ > \ 1 \ $ case, do you know the Intermediate Value or Mean Value Theorems?

Comment: No, sorry, I don't. I'm pretty new to logarithms. I'm still in grade 10, in India.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As said in the comments, you have two situations buit you can notice that for $x=1$, the lhs and rhs are equal.

So consider the case where $x=1-\epsilon$ and use Taylor expansion for the lhs at $x=1$. Yous will easily see that the inequality is not satisfied. Since you noticed that for $x=1$, $lhs=rhs$, the inequality will be satisfied for $x>1$. So, you can now forget the absolute value in the rhs.

Now, compute the derivative of $lhs-rhs$; it is equal to $3/x-1$ and so canceled for $x=3$; the second derivative being negative, then this point corresponds to a maximum. For $x=3$, $lhs=3 log(3)$ and $rhs=2$; so, at this point, $lhs > rhs$. On the other side, you know that $x$ moves faster then $log(x)$; so there is a point which will corresponds to an $x$ intercept. You will then need to solve the equation $$\log(x^3) = x-1$$ which does not any simple analytical solution. If you plot the function, you will see that the solution is close to $x=6.71$.

So, the inequality is satisfied for $1 < x < 6.71$

Comment: Just noticed an unfairly unaccepted answer.

Comment: @Siddhartha. Thank you ! Three and half years !!!

Comment: Hahaha I know I can be a tough customer ;)